# What does it mean to be self-organizing team in Agile Methodlogy?

Tags: software-development

As I am learning about Agile Methodology.Got confuse with Self- organizing team topic.I understood the theoretical concept of self-organizing team but  want to know how does it really work in organizations or in real time projects. Who Assign Task to Dev Team (DEV and QA)in Agile Scrum? Is it QA and Dev lead responsibility or  each team member by them self decide that they will be working on particular task?

Comment: Though Agile is used outside of software, might this be better suited to the software development or project management sites over the workplace?  Also, you might consider editing your question.  It's fairly difficult to read and may benefit from a little bit of fleshing out.

Answer (score 2):

One of the principles of Agile Software Development is that teams are self-organizing. This means that it is up to the teams to determine how much work they can achieve (with an appropriate level of confidence) and then how they will go about doing the work. Through experience, we've learned that pull-based systems are highly effective - people will pull work when they have the capacity to do it.

In the end, it's up to the team. But teams where the individuals understand the work that is necessary and can pull it into progress and get it to a state of completion is one of the most effective methods of getting work done.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the quick reply. I understand this concept of self-organizing team but was not able to visualize how does it work in real time project. So for example if there are 4 member in QA team how they divide the task . I need little more explanation with example. Because In other methodology mostly Team lead is responsible to divide the task among team .

Comment: @Justin That's actually part of the self-organizing.  During sprint planning, the team members themselves commit to the pieces they will take on and complete by sprint's end.  Leads and SMEs may have tendencies to suggest or push, but it is supposed to be finally up to the working resources to take on what they will.  Agile doesn't guarantee everyone pulls their share, but is a framework that encourages it.  If they don't, that's more of a management issue than a function of the process itself (though retrospectives arguably could lead to such revelations being aired).

Comment: Thanks Jhon your answer helped me a lot. As I am new to this community just wanted to know what is -3 voting stands for. What does it mean?